# Omnet++ Gate Index out of range

Tags: omnet++

I'm making a randomly generated network where the node will send an update massage after asking if the other node already know the update. Currently the update status is still predefined. I'm getting this error message when running the simulation:

```
send()/sendDelayed(): Gate index 1048576 out of range when accessing vector gate 'out[]' with size 1 -- in module (Sg1) Simplegossip1.node[2] (id=4), at t=0s event #1
```

Here's my code:

simplegossip1.ned

```
simple Sg1
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/routing");
        bool updated;
    gates:
        input in[];  // declare in[] and out[] to be vector gates
        output out[];
}

network Simplegossip1
{
    parameters:
        int count;
        double connectedness; // 0.0<x<1.0
        @display("bgb=640,444");
    submodules:
        node[count]: Sg1 {
            gates:
                in[];  // removed the size of gate
                out[];
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        for i=0..count-2, for j=i+1..count-1, if uniform(0,1)<connectedness {
            node[i].out++ --> node[j].in++;
            node[i].in++ <-- node[j].out++;
        }
}
```

Here's the cc file.
sg1.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

/**
 * First attempt for gossip protocol
 */
class Sg1 : public cSimpleModule
{
  protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(Sg1);

void Sg1::initialize()
{
    if (getIndex() == 0) {
        cMessage *askupdated = new cMessage("Ask Update");
        int m = gateSize("out");
        int l = intuniform(0, m-1);
        send(askupdated, "out",l);
    }
}

void Sg1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    //gate randomizer
    int n = gateSize("out");
    int k = intuniform(0, n-1);

    int sid = msg->getArrivalGateId();
    bool updatestatus = par("updated");
    EV << "Received message `" << msg->getName() << "', sending it out again\n";

    if (strncmp (msg->getName(),"Ask Update",2) == 0) {
        if (updatestatus == true){
            delete msg;
            cMessage *updated = new cMessage("Updated");
            send(updated, "out", sid);
        }
        else {
            delete msg;
            cMessage *unupdated = new cMessage("Unupdated");
            send(unupdated, "out", sid);
        }
    }
    else if (strncmp (msg->getName(),"Unupdated",2) == 0) {
        delete msg;
        cMessage *update = new cMessage("Here is the update");
        send(update, "out", sid);
    }
    else {
        delete msg;
        cMessage *askupdated = new cMessage("Ask Update");
        send(askupdated, "out", sid);
    }
}
```

And an omnet.ini file that only calling the Simplegossip1 network.

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
int sid = msg->getArrivalGateId();
```

you read the **gate ID**. Then you use this value as a **gate index**:

```
send(updated, "out", sid);
```

However, a gate ID is not the same as gate index. Therefore there is an error during `send()`.
In the simulation every object (e.g. module, gate, message) has a unique number (i.e. ID). It is clearly mentioned in
[OMNeT++ Simulation Library](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cMessage.html#ac8a15c06811a2422a6e85b842980e5e3).
You should check the current size of the gate and be sure that you do not try to send via index out of scope.

Comment: I tried msg->getArrivalGate()->getIndex() and it works. Thanks for your help.